# How to use awk/sed/grep to filter out only the latest string in a real-time log file

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk, grep

this thing is really confusing me. Suppose I have a file like this

```
09:35:24 03/04/2014  Pink Floyd the best band in the world KING KING
09:44:21 03/04/2014 Led Zeppelin the greatest hard rock band ever 
09:54:21 03/04/2014 Bon scott I love Bon scott KING KING
10:15:23 03/04/2014 AC/DC is the best
10:35:43 03/04/2014 It's all a joke 
12:46:55 03/04/2014 No value nothing is there here KING KING 
15:35:43 03/04/2014 It's all a joke1 
15:39:43 03/04/2014 It's all a joker KING KING
15:55:43 03/04/2014 It's all a jokeeyyyy
```

Now the above one is a file which will be created in the morning and it keeps appending till midnight. Now I have to extract lines where the pattern KING KING exists. Mine is a monitoring script so it checks this file every 60s for the pattern KING KING and if it exists I shall put it in a new file for further operations. Now if you see **timestamps** are different.At 10:15 I got the first 2 lines with the matching pattern. Now at 12:46 when I run the script I don't want the previously found Matching Pattern again 
I,e at 12:46 I only want `"12:46:55 03/04/2014 No value nothing is there here KING KING "` 
and not again the values at 09:54 and 09:35 (I,e Bon scott and Pink Floyd) So basically how do I use grep/sed/awk to filter only the latest and not give me the old ones. Thanks.

EDIT:

at 10:00 My script runs I grep for KING KING and get the Pink Floyd and Bon Scott lines. Now again (say) at 16:00 My script runs I only want the strings

```
12:46:55 03/04/2014 No value nothing is there here KING KING
```

and

```
15:39:43 03/04/2014 It's all a joker KING KING
```

and not the older ones. Please note there can be many occurrences of KING KING pattern not only 2.

Comment: Are you saying you want JUST the latest SINGLE line containing KING KING? If so, why not just use grep on KING KING then do tail -n 1?

Comment: Are the matching lines stored in the same format in which they are found? ie when you want to match the 12:46 line, is there a file somewhere which already has the 09:54 and 09:35 lines?

Comment: @Joe Exactly since I'm planning to put a sleep timer at every iteration I want only the latest strings matching KING KING. So at 15:39 if you would assume I want only "15:39:43 03/04/2014 It's all a joker KING KING" and not the previously grep'd values. Thanks

Comment: @ Josh. No this is the only log file that I have that keeps updating at regular intervals. Based on this log file I have to extract the latest strings at periodic intervals (pattern with KING KING) and then use it further.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "KING KING" <your file> | tail -n 1
```

You said you only wanted the most recent line containing KING KING. You can use tail -n 1 to grab just the last one, which is the most recent one assuming your file appends, not prepends, lines.

If it prepends you can use `head` instead.

EDIT:

If you would like to look at the potentially new KING KING lines that may come in as your original log updates, you can use `tail -f` instead up there.

Otherwise, if you want just the latest one but you want it to update, you're going to have to keep polling it over and over.

Example:

```
while true
do
    grep "KING KING" <your file> | grep -vf <your temporary file>
    grep "KING KING" <your file> > <your temporary file>
    sleep 2
done
```

That's just off the top of my head. It might need some tweaks but I don't have access to a terminal right now. Also, you don't need to rewrite temp file every time, and you can use `cat` to just append to the end of your temp file but I'll leave it to you to work that one out though. :)

Comment: Ok very sorry not exactly the last one actually. Suppose if within the timer count expires  new  10 more occurrences of KING KING has come I need those latest values. So what logic should I use. Should I store everytime fetched values into a new file and then compare.?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you're saying. You want the latest some arbitrary number?  If you want more than the latest one you can just change the `tail -n 1` to `tail -n <#you want>`.  If whatever program it is you have keeps appending new stuff to your log and you want to keep looking at them as it updates, you're better off using `tail -f` which will spit out the new KING KING lines as your original log updates.

Comment: Are you saying you only want KING KING lines you haven't seen before? In that case you're going to need to keep a temporary file where you append the lines you've seen already, then every time do grep -vF against that file.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a temporary file with the day's previous matches in:

```
touch matches.txt
grep "KING KING" output.log | grep -vFf matches.txt | tee -a matches.txt
```

This will filter out any previous matches stored in `matches.txt`, and also appends the new matches to that file. You will need to empty this at midnight, presumably.